# Using a macro button to added new tabs based on a template and a list on a master sheet

Tags: vba, excel

i am trying to create a macro button that adds a new tab based on the list in the projects tab in column A. but if the tab already exists it dose not create one and find a task that dose not have a tab. i was using the question already asked on here ([Macro to create new tabs in Excel from a list in a Master tab and populate a cell in each tab with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881535/macro-to-create-new-tabs-in-excel-from-a-list-in-a-master-tab-and-populate-a-cel/51185989#51185989)) but i ran into problems:

i used this code but keep getting a run time error 1004 when i add a new item to my list in column A on the . how can i get this to update the master sheet. what i want is when an item is added to column A in Master tab i can click the button and update.

the code works when all items are listed in column A and i then press the button but as soon as i add a new item i get the error?

i have updated the code a little to fit my needs but its below:

```
Sub Add_Projet_Button()
    Dim masterSheet As Worksheet
    Dim hiddenSheet As Worksheet
    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
    Dim myBook As Workbook
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim namesColumn

    'Define your workbook - here set as the active workbook, assuming it contains 
    masterSheet and hiddenSheet
    Set myBook = ActiveWorkbook

    'Define your worksheets - The sheets are named "Master" and "Hidden" 
    respectively
    Set masterSheet = myBook.Worksheets("Projects")
    Set hiddenSheet = myBook.Worksheets("TEMPLATE")

    'Define which column in your master tab the list is - here it's A i.e. column 1
    namesColumn = 1

    'Find the last row of the sheets list
    lastRow = masterSheet.Cells(masterSheet.Rows.Count, namesColumn).End(xlUp).Row

    'Cycle through the list - Assuming the list starts in column "A" from the 2nd row
    For i = 3 To lastRow
        With myBook
            'New sheet
            Set NewSheet = .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets("Projects"))
        End With

        'Find name of the tab and naming the tab
        tabName = masterSheet.Cells(i, namesColumn)
        NewSheet.Name = tabName

        'Copy from hidden template - You can choose the ranges if predefined or use .Cells(r,c) to do something fancier
        hiddenSheet.Range("A1:BF950").Copy _
          Destination:=NewSheet.Range("A1:BF950")

        'Paste in e.g. cell A1 i.e. (1,1) the tab name
        NewSheet.Cells(2, 1).Value = tabName
    Next i
End Sub
```

can someone help??

thanks!

Comment: Which line do you get the error? Please note that [“Can someone help me?” is not an actual question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: the error occurs on line 32 (    NewSheet.Name = tabName)

Comment: ① use `Option Explicit` and declare **all** your variables, `tabName` is not declared! ② Sheet names are limited to 31 characters. So you might use something like `NewSheet.Name = Left$(tabName, 31)`.

Comment: Sorry kind of new to this, but i still get the error on that line after changing it to your suggestion?

Comment: Please update your code where you declared **all** your variables. Debug your code, go through it step-by-step (with F8). What is the value in `tabName` when the error occurs? Make sure it dosn't contain any of these characters `* / \ [ ] : ?` which are not allowed in sheet names.

Comment: ok will try this, the value is: tabname = masterSheet.Cells(i, namesColumn)

Comment: no that's not the actual value. This `masterSheet.Cells(i, namesColumn)` refers to a value but I wanted to know what the value (the actual name that sheet will be) is.

Comment: i see, this will be defined in the Projects tab in column A. so if there is a value there it creates a new sheet from the hidden template and gives it the value in column A. i debugged the whole script and i still get a run time error on NewSheet.Name = Left$(tabname, 31) how would i declare this variable? i already have: Sub Add_Projet_Button()
Dim masterSheet As Worksheet
Dim hiddenSheet As Worksheet
Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
Dim myBook As Workbook
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim namesColumn
Dim tabname

Comment: `Dim tabName As String` • When you get the error. What is the exact value in `tabName` then? What is the actual name you want to give that sheet? (Tell the exact value, not in which cell it is.)

Comment: i might be misunderstanding here but what do i put for a value that is contently changing? the tab name is determined by what is in column A and that does not already exist as a new tab?

Comment: yes but at the time when the error occurs the variable `tabname` has a value (which was read from the cell). Select that variable name and press Shift+F9 to see its value at the time of error.

Comment: thanks for your help got it working now!